Performing gates and measurements on 2D cluster states in MBQC
I've been going through various papers on MBQC for a while now, and I am still not clear on how we perform gates on 2D cluster states. On 1D clusters it's very clear, just a series of measurements in either the $X$ or a rotated basis $\{|0\rangle + |1\rangle, |0\rangle +e^{-i\theta} |1\rangle \}$. Each measurements generates $Z^{m}HU$, where $U^{\dagger}XU$ generates the rotated basis. Due to the by-product operators$$U_{Z}(\theta)\to U_{Z}(\theta(-1)^{m})\,,$$ due to the propogation of by-product operators to the end of the circuit. This leads to measurement adaptivity, ie alteration of the sign of the measurement basis after we get a measurement outcome so that it will still implement the transformation we want.
However, I am having trouble on how these by-product operators come about, and the teleportation of the state, when we move to 2D clusters. In general, I cannot find concrete sources or examples of how 2 qubit gates are actually implemented, and why it works, An example I am looking at, but having issue with, is the following representation of a CNOT gate on a 4 qubit cluster:

Specifically figure 2.(a) in A One-Way Quantum Computer. They state that the end state should be $$|s_{1}\rangle_{x,1}\otimes|s_{2}\rangle_{x,2}\otimes U_{\Sigma}^{34}(|i_{4}\rangle_{z,4}\otimes|(i_{1}+i_{4}) mod 2\rangle_{z,3})$$ with $$U_{\Sigma}^{34}=\sigma_{z}^{3^{s1+1}}\sigma_{x}^{3^{s2}}\sigma_{z}^{4^{s1}}$$
Now maybe I have missed something obvious in the literature, but it's not clear to me how they are arriving at this. Given a starting state of, for example, $$|0\rangle_{z,1}\otimes|1\rangle_{z,4}\otimes|+\rangle_{x,2}\otimes|+\rangle_{x,3}\,,$$ after performing the $CZ$ operations between 1 and 2, 2 and 3 and 2 and 4, and measuring 1 and 2, after measuring the readout, ie 3 and 4, and reordering them gives $$|-\rangle_{x,1}\otimes|-\rangle_{x,2}\otimes|0\rangle_{x,3}\otimes |1\rangle_{z,4}$$ with
$$U_{\Sigma}^{34}=\sigma_{x}^{3}\sigma_{z}^{4}$$
which means, discounting $U_{\Sigma}^{34}$, I have $|-\rangle_{x,1}\otimes|-\rangle_{x,2}\otimes|1\rangle_{x,3}\otimes |1\rangle_{z,4}$, which is the desired outcome of flipping qubit 1 based on qubit 4 being $|1 \rangle$.
What I would like to understand is how the byproduct operators emerge as a result of the measurements., ie where Z and H emerge from. I feel like most of the literature on MBQC really does ignore higher dimensional clusters despite their importance w.r.t examples, with few solid ones of how 2d is meant to work. Most of it focuses on eigenvalue and stabilizer formalism, but as I havent't work with computations in this manner, I am unsure how it progresses.
Edit: Taking a look at Measurement-based quantum computation with cluster states, the general method is to update the eigenvalue equations or the stabilizers with commuting stabilisers given the measurements. But what is not clear to me is how we can take the starting set of stabilizers for the cluster state, and get the end by-product operations from them. These are the starting stabilizers, but the usual process of taking the anti-commuting ones and taking their product, and introducing the new stabilizer doesn't work here, as we have measurement results. Additionally, it isn't clear how the bi-product operators emerge from this.
$$\{ \sigma_{x}^{1}\sigma_{z}^{2},\sigma_{x}^{4}\sigma_{z}^{2},\sigma_{x}^{3}\sigma_{z}^{2},\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{z}^{1}\sigma_{z}^{3}\sigma_{z}^{4} \}$$ Th

Hi @NorbertSchuch. I'm not really sure what your comment means with regards to me claiming the problem is with others? I didn't blame anyone in my post. I said I don't see or I don't understand. If you are referring to my bottom post, I don't see how that could be take as claiming the problem is with others. Pointing out a lack of examples on 2D and higher computations on clusters states in the literature is a valid and reasonable statement. You may not agree with it, but it's not a comment that can be phrased as saying the problem is with others.

"Just because there are more works one 1D, doesn't mean the 2D case isn't understood"  You're putting words in my mouth. Again, nowhere in my post did I blame other people or authors, or claim they didn't understand anything. The question I am asking is literally w.r.t an example of 2D cluster state computation, so it's clearly understood- I'm saying I do not understand, and would like help with the example given, as 2D and higher is ignored in the literature. There are very few worked examples. This one in the original one-way paper is the only one I could find.

Fair enough, working out the 2D case in detail is probably a bit a pain (which doesn't mean it's not understood!), so people are not eager to write it out in detail in papers. It is probably better put on a computer. -- Now I think after taking out the 2nd graph, the question is more clear. Still, I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect. (In particular, I find the calculation you present doesn't quite help.) -- On a very general level, I think one can show using the stablizer formalism that for any graph state and Pauli measurements, you end up with a Clifford gate with byproduct operators

I'll try to write sth if I have time ...

Ok so I've rewrote the question with more of a focus on how the operators emerge w.r.t the measurements in the eigenvalue equation or stabilizer formalism, as in a lof of the papers this seems to be the only description they give of how the computation works with higher dimensional states.

It's going to depend heavily on how the 2d structure is arranged, but my main way of understanding these situations is, think of the 1D wires as qubits which flow down the wire and the CZ connecting different wires, simply as a CZ between the qubits on those wires.
In Fig A, lets say we start with the initial state $|\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle$ (no reason it is not already entangled). We measure  the first qubit such that the angle is 0, so after the measurement (up to some paulis and adaptive measurements) $(H\otimes I)|\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle$. We then perform a $CZ$ between the two wires and have $CZ(H\otimes I)|\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle $. Finally we perform another measurement on the top qubit so have $(H\otimes I)CZ(H\otimes I)|\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle = CX_{2,1} |\psi\rangle |\phi \rangle$ as required.

... modulo the byproduct operators, which however do not affect the CZ gate.

So I am having trouble following some of this. The $CZ$ build up the cluster, and generally we perform them at the start. Your first measurment in the $X$ basis propogates $|\psi\rangle$ to the second qubit, with a bi-product $H$. We'll say for simplicity that the measurement outcome was 0 so there is no bi-product $Z$. But now you have $$C_{Z_{2,3}}C_{Z_{2,4}}H_{2} |\psi\rangle_{2} \otimes |+\rangle_{3} \otimes |C\rangle_{4} $$ Here's my issue. There's 1 last measurement on 2 to perform. So how does the remaining measurement affect these last to $CZ$'s to lead to H on only the first?
